# Adding a custom page to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

All I want from WP is use of its login and some of its plug ins (for authorization). The pages themselves are all unique and have to be custom built from scratch for both style and function.

I looked into page templates but those seem to be more geared towards building templates, which I don't need.

What is the simplest way to add custom PHP pages to WP while having access to its user authentication?